# Why output of boost::adaptors::filtered has no member named size?

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, c++14, monads

The following dummy program compiles and runs

```cpp
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using boost::adaptors::filtered;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
auto whatever = [](auto&& x){ return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); };
auto whenever = [](auto&){ return true; };

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    auto w1 = v | transformed(whatever);
    auto w2 = v | transformed(whatever) | filtered(whenever);
    w1.size();
    //w2.size();
}
```

uncommenting the commented line and attempting a compilation with `g++ -std=c++14 that_file.cpp` causes this error:

```cpp
uffa.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
uffa.cpp:17:8: error: ‘struct
boost::range_detail::filtered_range<<lambda(auto:2&)>, const
boost::range_detail::transformed_range<<lambda(auto:1&&)>, std::vector<int> >
>’ has no member named ‘size’
   17 |     w2.size();
      |        ^~~~
```

Since `filtered`, just like `transformed`, takes a range and returns a range, I don't understand why `size` is not available on `filtered`'s output.

I know that `transformed` and `filtered` are two different mathematical functions (e.g. the former assumes that its input is a functor, whereas the latter assumes, correct me if I'm wrong, that its input is a monad), but still... here the input is a `std::vector` so what's wrong with asking the `size` of the output of `filtered`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you transform a range, the size doesn't change.  That means `transform` can known what the size will be, as it's the same as the input.

When you filter a range, you may or may not be removing elements from the range.  This is done lazily, so you can't know until you go through the filtered range how large it will be.  If you do a non-lazy filter you can know, but ranges are supposed to be lazy.

Comment: Oh, so it's all because of lazyness. Thanks, I'll accept asap.

Comment: @Enlico Yep.  If you don't actually evaluate the filter you can't know the resulting size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `boost::size`:

```
boost::size(w2)
```

but it may be costly in terms of performance.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer because it addresses the _why_ of the error I got. However this answer adds a lot by adding a possible solution, `boost::size`, and telling me that it forces the evaluation of the range.